# Decoding negative numbers as float from Hexidecimal string?

Tags: c#, hex

I have a hexidecimal string that is number values, coming over serial from an external device. I am decoding them a block at a time using:

```
string tmpValue(incoming hex data, such as FE7258);

int valueInt = Convert.ToInt32(tmpValue, 16);
float XCoord = ((float)valueInt / 100);
```

I am able to check the output of XCoord against the device output, and when the numbers are positive, this works as expected. When they are negative, however, my results jump to incorrect.

Even using this online converter:

[hex-to-decimal converter](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.htm)

I see that when a negative number is converted and then converted back, it is no longer the same number.

Is there a way around this? How can i deal with negative values in a hex - to - float conversion?

Comment: How many characters long is your hex representation? It has to be a fixed number I presume

Comment: It is a longer string that I have split to give the values that i need. For example, an input of `FE7258` should be giving me something like `-108100`, and instead it is outputting `16675416`

Comment: *Negative* numbers are usually represented as *complement* ones. So when negative number should be encoded as hex the number is represented as complement and this value is encoded. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a simple C# conversion to get back to the negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with *negative numbers* we're actually using *complement* ones:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

I.e. instead of negative `-x` we use

```
-x == ~x + 1
```

E.g. for `-123` we have

```
  123     = 0000 0000 0111 1011 (binary)
 ~123     = 1111 1111 1000 0100
 ~123 + 1 = 1111 1111 1000 0101 (binary) == FF85 (Hex)
```

When you convert `FF85` back, you have two options:

- Treat `FF85` as *2 byte* signed value (and you'll get `-123` back)
- Treat `FF85` as *4 byte* signed value or 2 byte *unsigned* (and you'll get `65413`)

In your case (strange **3 byte** integer value)

```
private static String ToHex(int value) {
  return (value & 0xFFFFFF).ToString("X6");
}

private static int FromHex(String value) {
  int v = Convert.ToInt32(value, 16);

  unchecked {
    return (v <= 0x7FFFFF) ? v : v | (int)0xFF000000;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
int x = -123;

// FFFF85
string hex = ToHex(x);

// Back -123
int back = FromHex(hex); 

// -101800
Console.Write(FromHex("FE7258"));
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! How can I get the negative values back from the hex data?

Comment: You just reverse the operation, x = ~(x - 1); However, I don't know how you'll know when to perform this operation as there needs to be some demarkation of when a value is to be interpreted as negative.

Comment: The OP's sample values appear to be 6 characters (3 bytes) long. Some padding might be needed on the initial string to int conversion.

Comment: Please forgive my idiocy, but how can I `Treat FF85 as 2 byte signed value`?

Comment: @anti: e.g. `unchecked { Int16 x = (Int16) 0xFF85; ...}` - given `0xFF85` I want to have `Int16` (signed 2 byte value) as a result.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. My hex string looks like  `FE7258`, stored as `string tmpValue`. When i try:

`unchecked { Int16 valueInt = (Int16)tmpValue; }`

it `cannot convert string to short`

Comment: @anti: please, notice that you seem to have **3 byte** integer (in my answer I use **2 byte** ones); `FE7258` == `-101800`

Comment: THANK YOU! I have been tearing my hair out with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using non-standard byte sizes, for example three bytes as your question posts, you can perform the conversion with simple subtraction:

```
public static int ThreeByteHexToSignedInt(string hex)
{
    var val = Int32.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

    if(val > 0xEFFFFF) // If greater than maximum postive 3 byte int
    {
        val = val - 0xFFFFFF - 1; // take the compliment
    }

    return val;
}
```

For example:

```
ThreeByteHexToSignedInt("000001"); // Returns 1
ThreeByteHexToSignedInt("FFFFFF"); // Returns -1
ThreeByteHexToSignedInt("FE7258"); // Returns -101800
ThreeByteHexToSignedInt("00FFFE"); // Returns 65534
```

For float / double, you can just take the result of this operation and perform direct casting, or use the `Convert` static class.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @anti, np, i think most of us do this for fun :)